# name for a certain action when exchanging numerator and denominator in an equation

Tags: terminology

In an equation

$ 4 = \frac{32}{ 8}$

You can exchange the denominator on the right side with the numerator of the left side.

$  8 = \frac{32}{4}$

Is there a name for this action / process?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Use MathJax while writing next time-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have people decided this process needs a name?

Comment: @mrob, depending on what you mean, I'd argue that people haven't decided this process needs a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for, so here are two guesses:

### 1: The operation done to the equation

You have:

- "multiplied both sides of the equation by $8$ and then divided both sides by $4$"
- or "divided through by $4$ and then multiplied through by $8$"
- or simply "multiplied both sides of the equation by 2"

For example, $4=\dfrac{32}8\to4*8=32\to8=\dfrac{32}4$.

### 2: The idea behind that operation

You may be thinking about/using the ["commutative property of multiplication"](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) to change the division sentence you're writing. Since $4*8=8*4=32$, you can
write either division sentence and they're both valid.

---

#### On "cross-multiplication"

I don't think "cross-multiply" should be used for this operation (as a couple have suggested in deleted answers). Since 4 ends up in a denominator, it's not getting multiplied. Additionally, this is not an example of the three different things people usually call "cross-multiplication"; for more details, see [Nix the Tricks](http://www.nixthetricks.com/)

Comment: thanks for your comment. I thought that 4 is multiplied to 1 in the fenominator and 8 to 1 in the numerator.

Comment: @vidyarthi That would certainly involve two multiplications, but would be a (new?) meaning that isn't one of the most common two/three for the phrase.